# Reading .py scripts in Windows 7

Tags: python

I have Python 3 and a folder with a simple `.py` file which says `Hello World`. I navigate to the file using the `os.chdir("path-to-file")`, and, after that I type the name of the file in my Python command line (for ex. `demo.py`). Everytime I do this, I get an error that says:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'demo' is not defined`

Anyway, when I run the python script in a simple, Windows command line, it is runnning good. Why is this?

By the way, any additional reading list/links about Python would be helpful.

Comment: It fails due to the same reason it would fail if you add the line `demo.py` in a Python program: it's not valid Python code. The Python "command line" is an interactive programming environment, it's not a shell environment like the Windows command line.

Comment: So, how should I read a simple .py file in the Python command line?

Comment: The same way you do in a Python program: you don't. If anything you `import demo` as a module, but that gets tricky with how modules are located while you're in interactive mode. To execute a `.py` file you do it on the Windows command line, as you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the script from the command line:

```
$ python3 /path/to/file
```

You don't really want to run a script inside the python interpreter unless all of the code is contained inside a function or a class. Let's say that your file `script.py` looks like this:

```
print("Beep boop")
```

you could load this file in the python interpreter by importing it

```
>>> os.chdir("path/to/file")
>>> import script
Beep boop
```

but this is the wrong way of going about this. `import` is used for sharing code between files - not executing code. If `script.py` instead looked like this:

```
def main():
    print("Beep boop")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then you could run it like this

```
>>> os.chdir("path/to/file")
>>> import script
>>> script.main()
Beep boop
```

or like this:

```
$ python3 /path/to/file
Beep boop
```

You will also need a file called `__init__.py` in the same directory as `script.py` for the first method to work.

I'd recommend you do some reading about how to use the command line, it's frustrating at first but well worth the effort.